# multinominal regression model on continuous output

Tags: r, logistic-regression, multinomial

I used a multinomial logistic regression on a csv file (3400 records) and the continuous independent variables has too many different variables (2500).
When I run the multinominal regression model it takes too much time and then failed to result.
I also assigned the `MaxNWts = 1000000`.
Do you have any idea?

Comment: As you pointed out, you have too many categories for the model to estimate.

Comment: is there any solution for not getting failed?

Comment: Reduce the number of categories by grouping them up in some way, or get more data with enough observations in each of the categories.